# Is anything wrong in my code that I can't put data in Realtime DB in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

What I'm trying to do is put some data from app to Firebase Realtime Database with Authentication.
I am trying get UserID from authentication and put with another data from app to my database but nothing change when I look at database, there is no datas.
I've got all dependencies that I need and no errors occurs.

At the end of project>app>build.gradle i've got implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0' . Is it correct? Or should be there apply plugin com.google.gms.google-services ?

```
public class RejestracjaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private Button mRegister;
        private EditText mEmail, mPassword, mName;
    
        private RadioGroup mRadioGroup;
    
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthStateListener;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_rejestracja);
    
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            firebaseAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    if (user != null) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RejestracjaActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            };
    
            mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    
            mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    
            mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    
            mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int selectId = mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    
                    final RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectId);
    
                    if (radioButton.getText() == null) {
                        return;
                    }
    
                    final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                    final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                    final String name = mName.getText().toString();
                    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(RejestracjaActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(RejestracjaActivity.this, "sign_up_error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                //reference to database
                                DatabaseReference currentUserDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);
                                Map userInfo = new HashMap<>();
                                userInfo.put("name", name);
                                userInfo.put("płeć", radioButton.getText().toString());
                                userInfo.put("profileImageUrl", "default");
                                currentUserDb.updateChildren(userInfo);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
        }
    }
```

All rules are set true in Database.
Debugger says:

1. E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for
   com.google.android.gms.chimera
2. E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load IDynamiteLoader from GmsCore:
   Application package com.google.android.gms not found
3. E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load IDynamiteLoader from GmsCore:
   Application package com.google.android.gms not found
4. E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for
   com.google.android.gms.phenotype

I also checked debugger and it reaches all lines but what concerns me is this line:

```
currentUserDb.setValue(name);
```

because it point out some strange URL repo.

I checked also google-services.json and firebase URL is good.

Comment: Did you already step through the code in a debugger? Does it ever reach the line that writes to the database? Does the map contain any values at that point? I also recommend adding a completion listener to the DB write as shown here: https://gist.github.com/puf/4a94a01e3c2510298ee46d0a7f90ab75

Comment: It reaches all the lines. Yes, it does. I edited my post and there is more information at the end.

Comment: "it point out some strange URL repo." What does that mean? Can you show the value you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DatabaseReference currentUserDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                            .getReference().child("Users").child(userId);`
```

This is what is causing the error.

Change it to:

```
DatabaseReference currentUserDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                            .getReference("Users").child(userId);
```

Comment: Both lines of code do the exact same thing. Can you please explain how does your answer solve OP's problem?

Comment: there is no difference, but I encountered the same problem once and changing the code worked for me, even I am surprised as to why that happened but it did happen !

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: exactly, it doesnt make sense to me too, but changing the code worked for me, so i suggested it to OP, and looks like it worked for him as well !